# how can I add a swf over a swf on a html page

Tags: html, flash

I've been trying to add a swf over a swf on a html page, it's working fine in Firefox, but in IE, the one that's added first is always on top of the other one. I used z-index but it's not working, does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

I already added wmode:transparent, it is working in firefox but not in IE 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `wmode=transparent` to your movie parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use a background iframe...Here is a nice [jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) to handle it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In order for z-index to work on a given element in a page, this element must be positioned with `position: absolute` or `position: relative`. You also need to set the `wmode` parameter to `transparent` to allow the browser to position the flash content below other elements in a page.